# example of a open function such that the restriction is not open

Tags: general-topology

Give an example of a function $f:X \to Y$ and  a subset $A \subset X$ such that f is open but $f_A$, the restriction of $f$ to $A$ is not open.

Can someone help me please? Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by f is open?

Comment: @Rowan: It’s a standard notion: it means that if $U$ is open in the domain of $f$, then $f[U]$ is open in the codomain.

Answer (score 15):

HINT: Let $X=Y=\Bbb R$, take $f$ to be the identity function, and take $A$ to be a set that isn’t open in $X$.

Comment: Thanks, the example was easy to find

Comment: @Ryoma: You’re welcome.

Comment: @Ryoma: If you feel that this answer has satisfied your question, it is encouraged that you accept the answer. Since you haven't accepted any answers before (as of now), I thought I'd point out [this link](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) for your information.